# How to play multiple audio files sequentially in html 5?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I wanted to autoplay multiple audio files sequentially.

Below code plays all the audios at the same time.

```
<audio src="26de96c4000ceccafc415c5f191b5836.wav" autoplay ></audio>

<audio src="0001.wav" autoplay ></audio>
```

Please advice whether it can be played sequentially.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the "autoplay" attribute from the "audio" tags and [use javascript](http://web.archive.org/web/20160711042031/http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_a_playlist_for_html5_audio)

The method "ended" is called when one "audio" tag finishes:

```
<audio ... ended="nextAudioNode.play();">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp