# How to play multiple audio files one by one in html 5?

Tags: html5-audio

I would like to play multiple audio files one by one. I have read the same question, but I have found the links to the original answer not working and question unanswered.

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25767134/997646)

```
<audio id="mySound" controls><source src="http://www.hvalur.org/audio/uploaded_files/ds_umkomuleysi_0_0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

<audio id="mySound1" ><source src="http://www.hvalur.org/audio/uploaded_files/ds_ljosmyndavel_0_0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

I want the first sound started by the user action (pressing the play button) and then the following sound(s) playing one by one.
The usage of this example will be practising of understanding of the telephone numbers read by native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
var mySound = document.getElementById("mySound");
var mySound1 = document.getElementById("mySound1");
var mySound2 = document.getElementById("mySound2");
var mySound3 = document.getElementById("mySound3");

var mySoundArray = [mySound, mySound1, mySound2, mySound3];
var mySoundArrayPos = 0;

var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    mySound.play();
    mySoundArrayPos = 0;
    startSoundTimer();
});

const startSoundTimer = () => {
    var mySoundTimer = setInterval(() => {
        if (mySoundArray[mySoundArrayPos].currentTime >= mySoundArray[mySoundArrayPos].duration) {
            if (mySoundArrayPos < mySoundArray.length -1) {
                mySoundArrayPos += 1;
                mySoundArray[mySoundArrayPos].play();
            } else {
                clearInterval(mySoundTimer);
            }
        }
    }, 10);
};
```

I don't know if the 10ms are a bit too fast, but I think, it's legit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are several issues. 1) first version with mySound.play(); worked. but 2) I would need more than 2 files to play one by one 3) it playes only once, later only the first audio 4) in audio player the length of the bar corresponds only to length of the first audio. Thank you

Comment: The bar indicating the length can be hidden (not an important issue)...

Comment: I edited my answer. But again, this is really freestyle without testing. Drop another line, if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, it works by pressing the button (I have hided the controls), but it does not stop and repeats all the time.

Comment: Ah! I thought, you wanted to play it repeatetly. I adjused my answer again. Now it should stop after all sounds in the array were played.

Comment: Yes, it stops now, great. When I try to press the button again, it playes only first sound of that array...

Comment: I added `mySoundArrayPos = 0;` into the button click event. Try again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232559/discussion-between-kurt-lagerbier-and-chejnik).

Answer (score 0):

```
Javascript 
=============== `playaudio(i) {
    var thisme = this;
    var audio = new Audio(thisme.model.audioFiles[i].audioUrl);
    audio.play();    
      audio.addEventListener("ended", function () {
        i = i + 1;
        console.log(i);
        if (i < thisme.model.audioFiles.length) {
          audio.src = thisme.model.audioFiles[i].audioUrl;
          audio.play();
        }
    }, false);
    }    
  }`



HTML
====`<span class='chunkAudio' (click)="playaudio(0)">
           <img class='playbtn' src="{{model.playerImageUrl}}" />
        </span>`
```